# What is this flower with mind-blowing red color?

Tags: identification

I found this flower in my garden.  I would like to know what it is. Zone 7

Although it seems as if there are two kinds of red flowers in the photo??

[image]

Comment: Need more info. What type of plant: tree, shrub, small, large, leaf shape, anything you think might be useful. The two flowers are probably different sexes in different flowers, male/female. Perfectly normal for some species, botanical term dioecious might be helpful. Are they growing from the same or different plants...

Comment: The flowers are different colours because some are older than others, the less vividly coloured ones are starting to fade. How tall is this plant and can we have a clear picture of the foliage please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main red flowers in your photo belong to an annual flowering plant commonly called "scarlet flax" (Linum grandiflorum). It is native to Algeria, but has been introduced wild in several other countries. It is a desirable garden flower.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linum_grandiflorum

https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/flowers/flax/scarlet-flax-care.htm